# Nginx resolver address from /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to set `resolver` address in nginx proxy configuration from `/etc/resolv.conf`?

It can be useful for example in docker or in virtualenvironment.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no easy way to do this because nginx use it's own resolver implementation. The two solutions I see are :

1) You generate the resolver list from a script and include it, e.g. :

`echo resolver $(awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "} $1=="nameserver" {print $2}' /etc/resolv.conf) ";" > /etc/nginx/resolvers.conf`

```
http {

    include resolvers.conf;

}
```

2) You recompile nginx with a third party module like the (very) experimental [perl module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html) and write a variable handler :

```
http {

    perl_modules perl/lib;
    perl_set $resolvers '

        sub {
            return system("awk BEGIN{ORS=\" \"} /nameserver/{print \$2}" /etc/resolv.conf");
        };

    resolver "$resolvers";
}
```

Now, if you are a hell of a C coder (prepare your eyes for some blood), you can still write an alternative patch or module to make it work this way.

Comment: thanks for the nice script (1)!

Comment: Do you know _which_ name servers Nginx uses by default?

Answer (score 14):

If you're using the Openresty version of nginx then you can use their special `local` argument to the `resolver` directive which when set to `local=on`, means the standard path of `/etc/resolv.conf` will be used by the resolver (for more details see [Openresty resolver docs](https://github.com/openresty/openresty/#resolvconf-parsing)):

```
resolver local=on;
```

Comment: Thank you! This indeed works with OpenResty. For the reference this is the container version I tried it with: `openresty/openresty:1.15.8.2-6-buster-fat`. I really like this solution since it is environment agnostic and does not require any fragile scripting tricks.

Answer (score 12):

For Kubernetes, you can simply add `kube-dns` as resolver.
The FQDN of the resolver is based on the namespace, by default `kube-system`.
You might have to change the FQDN to accommodate your configuration.

```
location / {
   ...
   resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local;
   ...
}
```

You can read more about DNS and services here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Comment: Didn't know that. But that was very useful, thank you!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22259088/1129682 how and why this works.

Answer (score 9):

For Docker users, solution found [here](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/658):

> Heres a workaround for people using Docker.

```
export NAMESERVER=`cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep "nameserver" | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' '`
```

> What this does is take all the `nameserver` entries from
>   `/etc/resolv.conf` and print them in a line, so you can use them with
>   nginx's `resolver` directive. Your Dockerfile will need to have a
>   custom script for the entrypoint that generates the config file and
>   then starts nginx. Lets say you have a file called
>   `nginx.conf.template` that looks something like:

```
...snip...
http {
  server {

    resolver $NAMESERVER valid=10s;

    ...snip....  
    }
  }
}
```

> Your startup script can then use the `envsubst` program to generate an `nginx.conf` and then start nginx. eg:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$NAMESERVER" == "" ]; then
    export NAMESERVER=`cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep "nameserver" | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' '`
fi

echo "Nameserver is: $NAMESERVER"

echo "Copying nginx config"
envsubst '$NAMESERVER' < /nginx.conf.template > /nginx.conf

echo "Using nginx config:"
cat /nginx.conf

echo "Starting nginx"
nginx -c /nginx.conf -g "daemon off;"
```

NOTE that in docker this tend to result in the same file, as by default the docker embedded DNS server is `127.0.0.11`, see [this answer to Docker Network Nginx Resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744650/docker-network-nginx-resolver/37656784#37656784).

Comment: Awk, learn it, it's a fantastic tool for text munging: `export NAMESERVER=$(awk '/^nameserver/{print $2}' /etc/resolv.conf)`. No need for `cat`, `grep` or `tr` in there.

Comment: this doesn't work on Kubernetes though.

Comment: I used `NGX_DNS_RESOLVER=$(awk '/nameserver/{a=(a?a" "$2:$2)} END{print a}' /etc/resolv.conf 2> /dev/null)`

Comment: For docker users, I recommend putting `exec ` at the front of the bottom line. It makes nginx PID 1, so that commands like `docker kill --signal=HUP <container>
` (reload config) work.

Answer (score 2):

If your system uses resolvconf (as many virtual machines do, but unfortunately Docker does not, see `man 8 resolvconf`), you might create the nginx `resolvers.conf` (as in the other answer) in `/etc/resolvconf/update-libc.d/nginx`. This behaves nicely even in the rare case of dynamic change of resolvers.

```
#!/bin/sh
conf="resolver $(/usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "} $1=="nameserver" {print $2}' /etc/resolv.conf);"
[ "$conf" = "resolver ;" ] && exit 0
confpath=/etc/nginx/conf.d/resolvers.conf
if [ ! -e $confpath ] || [ "$conf" != "$(cat $confpath)" ]
then
    echo "$conf" > $confpath
    service nginx reload >/dev/null
fi
exit 0
```

Some linux distributions include `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf` in their default configuration. Reload is usually ignored when service is not running. Notice the script may be run without `/usr/bin` in PATH, so you may need absolute path to awk.